# How to login a user on a REST API using restful-keystone

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I am trying to expose a model created with keystonejs over a REST API using [restful-keystone](https://github.com/d-pac/restful-keystone). The API should allow to create a new user or to retrieve the information of a user. This is my code

```
var beforeRetrieve = function (req, res,next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    next();
};

restful.expose({
    User: {
        show : ["_id","name", "email", ],
        methods: ["retrieve", "create"]
    }
}).before({
    User: {
        retrieve: [beforeRetrieve, middleware.requireUser],
        create: [],
    }
}).start();
```

The code is working but I am getting confused. `console.log(req.user);` is printing `undefined` which is logic. But how can I make it work and print the user initiating the request? Shall I include the user cookies in the request? Shall I create another API that allow the user to login and get the cookies/token? Is there already one in keystone? Can you please give me some idea on how to achieve that? My ideal case is to allow anyone to create a new user. By creating the new user a token should be returned and used in the future to identify the user. I am not sure how shall I proceed, can you please help me with some ideas, I am really confused

Comment: Is there an expressJS part?

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly check if you are using Keystone v4.0 but restful-keystone is supporting Keystone v0.3. For Keystone you can expose REST API without any additional modules.

For example you can edit routes/index.js to add a route:

```
// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    // API
    app.get('/api/user', routes.api.user.get);

};
```

And then create route/api/user.js to capture the REST reqeust:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var cdf = keystone.list('User');

exports.get = function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

But for user model, there is a ready-made REST API, but this requires Admin Permission:

http://server:port/keystone/api/users